# How to add seperate classes to no-search-result and found-search-result pages on wordrpess search - is_search()

Tags: php, functions, search, body-class

I want to add seperate body classes for no search result and found search result pages on wordrpess search.

I used that code but it isn't working - > what's the error here and what is the solution

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_class', 1 ); function custom_class( $classes ) {
    if ((is_home() && !is_front_page()) || (is_search()) || is_tag() || is_author()) {
        $classes[] = 'archive';
    }
    if (is_singular('page') || is_404() || (is_search() && 0 === $wp_query->found_posts )) {
        $classes[] = 'single';
    }
    return $classes; }
```

Comment: please help me to do this ?